# Strange error with rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I've googled this and there seems to be nothing on it.

This error occurred when trying to set up devise for my project.
Having bundle installed devise into my Gemfile with `gem "devise"`, I ran `rails g devise:install`, and then `rails g devise authorize`.  devise authorize created some db migrations, and upon migrating these changes, I got this:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:14:in `assign_attributes'
```

I should be on the most recent delayed_jobs (3.2.4 according to Gemfile.lock).  If the issue truly is in attribute_assignment.rb and I fix it locally, when I push my code into production won't it just break there?  Is this an issue that anybody else has seen before?  Is the issue with Devise, or with something else?  How do I fix this?

I don't really even know where to start with this, but I've tried bundle update, I've searched this error on google for a while, trying different combinations, taking similar search topics & researching, and I'm totally lost.  I've found nothing related.  I don't know the true source of the error, or anything.  I'm not even sure what I'm looking for.

Rails 4.1.2

Ruby 2.0

Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Full output-

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20140609160442 DeviseCreateAuthorizes: migrating ===========================
-- create_table(:authorizes)
   -> 0.1993s
-- add_index(:authorizes, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0559s
-- add_index(:authorizes, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0561s
== 20140609160442 DeviseCreateAuthorizes: migrated (0.3121s) ==================

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:14:in `assign_attributes'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/attr_encrypted-1.3.2/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:17:in `perform_attribute_assignment'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/attr_encrypted-1.3.2/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:24:in `assign_attributes_with_attr_encrypted'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.7/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/core.rb:8:in `init_attributes'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.7/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/validations.rb:15:in `create!'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1023:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:993:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `block in transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:209:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:201:in `transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activerecord-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/josh/TG/tax-guard-internal/bin/rake:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@latest/gems/activesupport-4.1.2.rc1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
/home/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
/home/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
-e:1:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

The migration- (this is automatic, I didn't write it & don't know much about it.)

```
class DeviseCreateAuthorizes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:authorizes) do |t|
      ## Database authenticatable
      t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
      t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""

      ## Recoverable
      t.string   :reset_password_token
      t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

      ## Rememberable
      t.datetime :remember_created_at

      ## Trackable
      t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
      t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
      t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
      t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
      t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

      ## Confirmable
      # t.string   :confirmation_token
      # t.datetime :confirmed_at
      # t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
      # t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable

      ## Lockable
      # t.integer  :failed_attempts, default: 0, null: false # Only if lock strategy is :failed_attempts
      # t.string   :unlock_token # Only if unlock strategy is :email or :both
      # t.datetime :locked_at


      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :authorizes, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :authorizes, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    # add_index :authorizes, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :authorizes, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

Rails 4.1.0 also does not work and errors as follows-

```
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Invoke db:load_config (first_time)
** Execute db:load_config
** Execute db:migrate
== 20140609160442 DeviseCreateAuthorizes: migrating ===========================
-- create_table(:authorizes)
   -> 0.2831s
-- add_index(:authorizes, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0666s
-- add_index(:authorizes, :reset_password_token, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0559s
== 20140609160442 DeviseCreateAuthorizes: migrated (0.4060s) ==================

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:14:in `assign_attributes'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/attr_encrypted-1.3.2/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:17:in `perform_attribute_assignment'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/attr_encrypted-1.3.2/lib/attr_encrypted/adapters/active_record.rb:24:in `assign_attributes_with_attr_encrypted'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.7/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/core.rb:8:in `init_attributes'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/core.rb:198:in `initialize'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:30:in `new'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/protected_attributes-1.0.7/lib/active_record/mass_assignment_security/validations.rb:15:in `create!'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1023:in `record_version_state_after_migrating'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:993:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `block in transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:219:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1038:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:991:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:953:in `block in migrate'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `each'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:949:in `migrate'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:807:in `up'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/josh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/home/josh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@410/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Comment: Can you post the migration file it fails on?

Comment: You are using `4.1.2.rc1`. Try to use other stable version, e.g. `4.1.0`. Probably, you encountered a bug.

Comment: @mkis- Migration added.

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev is there any definitive way to tell aside from downgrading & changing all my code?

Comment: I've run into this error when "has_secure_password" was defined... did the authorise model already exist? Does it have "has_secure_password" ?

Comment: @Crash sorry, I haven't got your question. Just to clarify – you could change rails version in Gemfile temporary for testing purposes.

Comment: @SteveTurczyn It does exist, but it does not have "has_secure_password".

Comment: @SergeyAlekseev acting on your hunch, I ran bundle update rails with `gem 'rails', '4.1.0'` and ran the migration.  I get the same error, except, as expected, this time the path shows it is pulling from the 4.1.0 directory instead.

Comment: See this issue: https://github.com/attr-encrypted/attr_encrypted/issues/107

Comment: @akatakritos- That seems to have done what I needed! Thank you.

Comment: @akatakritos (and Crash): Can you please post that as answer (and accept it)? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the protected_attributes gem installed (it is mentioned in your stack trace).  Could you double-check that the new attributes that these migrations are adding are listed in your various models' "attr_accessible" statements, then try running rake db:migrate again?